# Jquery live - launching a fancybox iframe

Tags: fancybox, jquery

So I have a an ajax table of results that have  tags links that allows you to edit the entries.

Currently the links  look like this `<a href="edit.php?id=$id">Edit Entry</a>`

What I want to do is open edit.php in a lightbox and send the id so as it is ajax I have to launch the lightbox using the live() function/

```
$("a.edit").live('click',function () { 


//fancy box code goes here, open edit.php?id=$id


   });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want to add `class="edit"` to the links, so the jQuery selector can use it.  After that, the following code should help out.  `ev.preventDefault()` will keep the browser from following the link, and allow you to implement the fancybox iframe instead.

```
$("a.edit").live("click",function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = this.href.match(/id=([0-9]*)/)[1];
    $.fancybox({
        href: "edit.php?id="+id,
        type: "iframe"
    })
});
```

You can add whatever fancybox settings you need, I just used the 2 for example.

Hope this helps.